# SVN, can't commit changes using Tortoise for a working copy that resides on Ubuntu 12.04 machine

Tags: windows, svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

I've recently set up an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine that I am using a local media server and web server for my projects.

My sites are run from ~/public_html on Ubuntu.  That folder was then mapped to my Windows 8 machine.  Previously I was using XAMPP, so I copied the contents of the htdocs/ folder to ~/public_html, this includes all the svn folders.

All sites are operating normally and are accessed via 192.168.1.10/SITE_NAME

Using NetBeans 7.2, the files are directly edited from the Windows machine.  When the changes are committed using Tortoise SVN, the following error is reported:

Error: Commit failed (details follow):

Error: Unable to make name in 'V:\SITE_NAME.svn\tmp'

This was after creating a new text document in the root directory of the site from the Windows machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't figure this out since I have full privileges on the folder.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning.  I can SSH into the Ubuntu server and run "svn commit" manually with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never use TortoiseSVN Working Copies on non-local drives
2. Check owner and permissions for files and folders in your WC
3. Change workflow and use post-commit hooks (server- or TSVN-side) to deploy code to site

[Additional reading](http://blog.grovehillsoftware.com/2009/09/subversion-odd-problems-and-funny.html)

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like I just need to run SVN commands from a shell on Windows.  I was hoping that I could keep my working copy on my test server and do everything from my Windows machine, but looks like I can't....

Comment: @KPheasey - you can, WC on Windows with TSVN, hooks and export - on server with CLI